# Yelp URL Encoding

Tags: urlencode, review, yelp

How do I encode the Yelp Review URL to also display the review text?

I got it down to where I can pre-fill the review to display a certain number of starts (e.g. 5 stars for the review below)

(NOT MY BUSINESS, JUST AN EXAMPLE)

`https://www.yelp.com/writeareview/biz/R9KSEEqy5yijjWovLgwYZw?return_url=%2Fbiz%2FR9KSEEqy5yijjWovLgwYZw&review_origin=biz-details-war-button&rating=5`

With the "&rating=5".

However, I am trying to figure out how to also add the text (I've tried multiple variations of "text", "review_text", etc.) so that if someone submits a form as part of an email follow-up sequence and fills out the review, they get automatically sent to Yelp and just have to hit submit instead of re-writing the whole review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to access the textarea element, because it does not exist - the field for the review description is actually a div (editable div with a text input role) because it has no id or name attribute you can't access it via request parameters. See, rating is the name of the radio box group, so passing a 5 as a parameter is acceptable; will populate the field - but not the review editor; it's several nested divs snd finally an editor (draft editor to be exact) which is also a div, but does not have an accessible method from the URL params.